# PhpStorm how to set up 'static::' instead of 'self::' in completion PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-completion

After clicking here

[image]

PhpStorm will insert `self::`

[image]

But I need always insert `static::` instead of `self::`

How to change this completion in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Live Template for that and use it instead. Check the values I have filled in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: If you use a variable placeholder (e.g. `$VAR$`) instead of `$END$` you can then force automatic code completion popup at that place (via "Edit Variables" button and using special expression for that variable there). This *may* work better than just `$END$` (that indicates the final caret position).